# Stretched background stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullscreen

I am working on an experimental art site that involves a grid of images each scaled to the size of the viewport. The background for the page body should be one stretched image and it was working at one point but has stopped functioning.  The background color shows and the image simply doesn't.  However if the background-size CSS is turned off in Chrome inspector it shows up at it's own size positioned top and left...

I am guessing that having body contain a box which amounts to 5 viewports wide and 5 viewports tall is messing with what the body element's size is?  Though allowing bg image to repeat didn't make it show up...

I resolved this by grabbing the screen width and height in the JavaScript and then setting background-size to those values like so:

`$('body,html').css('background-size',the_width + 'px ' + the_height+'px');`

But my question remains- why did the `background-size:100% 100%` stop working?

The page HTML looks like this only with 25 total divs and images.

```
<body>
<div id="box">
  <div class="full" id="full_10">
    <img src="home_tiles/10.jpg" width="800" height="600" title="10">
  </div>
  <div class="full" id="full_11">
    <img src="home_tiles/11.jpg" width="800" height="600" title="11">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

The CSS looks like this

```
  * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

  html, body { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color: #FF0000; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image:url(home_tiles/edge.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }

  img { display: block; }

  #box {
      position:absolute;
  }

  .full {
    float:left;
  }
```

The JavaScript sizing the images is

```
$(function() {  
  $('.full').hide();
  var win = $(window),
      fullscreen = $('.full'),
      image = fullscreen.find('img'),
      imageWidth = image.width(),
      imageHeight = image.height(),
      imageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
  var the_width; 
  var the_height; 
  var left_limit;
  var right_limit;   

  function resizeImage() {
    var winWidth = win.width(),
        winHeight = win.height(),
        winRatio = winWidth / winHeight;

    if(winRatio > imageRatio) {
      the_width = winWidth;
      the_height = Math.round(winWidth / imageRatio);
    } else {
      the_width =  Math.round(winHeight * imageRatio);
      the_height = winHeight;
    }

    left_limit = the_width * -2;
    right_limit = the_width * 2;

    image.css({
        width: the_width,
        height: the_height
    });
    $('#box').css({
      width: the_width * 5,
      height: the_height * 5,
      top: the_height * -2,
      left: the_width * -2
    });
  }

  win.bind({
    load: function() {
      resizeImage();
      $('.full').show('slow');
    },
    resize: function() {
      resizeImage();
    }
  });
```

Comment: do you really need that css class for _both_ html and body tags? can you try that only for body tag?

Comment: Interestingly it fails with just body.  Did not try with just html...